# SPACE BETWEEN TABLE AND TEXT

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table which I created in this way:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
\textlatin{ID} &\textlatin{ Name}   & \textlatin{Type}        & \textlatin{Label}                          & \textlatin{Values}            \\ \hline
1  & \textlatin{BED}    & \textlatin{numeric}     &\textlatin{ number of beds}                 & \textlatin{range}: 25-244     \\
2  & \textlatin{MCDAYS} & \textlatin{numeric}     & \textlatin{annual medical patient days}    & \textlatin{range: 48-514}     \\
3  & \textlatin{TDAYS}  & \textlatin{numeric}     & \textlatin{annual total patient days}      &\textlatin{range: 83-776}     \\
4  & \textlatin{PCREV}  &\textlatin{numeric}     & \textlatin{annual total care revenue}      &\textlatin{range}: 2853-36029 \\
5  & \textlatin{NSAL}   & \textlatin{numeric}     &\textlatin{ annual nursing salaries}        &\textlatin{range}: 1288-7489  \\
6  & \textlatin{FEXP}   &\textlatin{numeric}     & \textlatin{annual facilities expenditures} &\textlatin{range}: 137-6442   \\
7  & \textlatin{RURAL}  & \textlatin{categorical} &                                & \textlatin{rural , non rural } 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

The problem is that Latex created too much space between my paragraph and the tabular . How can I reduce this space?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon. And you'll get a faster answer if instead of posting a fragment of code you put the code into a complete compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: For example, you're using `\textlatin` in your fragment, but that's not a command that will be recognized without loading a package. So you need to make the code compilable. Are you sure you need a `table` environment here? You only need to use that environment if the `tabular` has a caption, and would be allowed to float to an arbitrary position relative to the rest of the text.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `too much space`. Better yet, please provide some code that actually generates an instance of "too much space".

Comment: `\begin{table}` means that table is a float that will be repositioned but you have used `[]` which means that it is not allowed to be re-inserted anywhere. Most likely latex warned  and replaced that by the default which is specified by the class which you have not shown but probably set it to `[tbp]`